# About Implicit Functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $x-u-v=0$ and $y-uv^{2}=0$, we can writte, u explicitly in term of x and y, then we can find by theorem of implicitly functions derivatives find the derivatives of v with respect to x and y, without care at the end about u.

In another example: $F[r,s,u,v]=0$, $r-u-e^u-v=0$ and $s-u v^{2}-\sin u$, where $r,s,u,v$ are all real valued functions of $x$ and $y$ in some open set of $\mathbb R^{2}$. In this example is hard to write $u$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, but is possible to find the derivatives in relation $x$ and $y$? Without care about $u$ and it derivatives.

I want to understand this and then generalize the idea, but if you know some generalization, please tell me :)

Answer (score 1):

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Although it is rather difficult to understand what you're asking because of what appears to be some formatting issues, I believe what you're looking for is a partial derivative with respect to $x$ and/or $y$. 

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $To take the partial derivative of a multivariable function, you simply treat the other variables that of which you are not differentiating as constants, as in this example: 
$$
f\left(x,y,z\right) = xy+\frac{\cos(z)}{x}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y-\frac{\cos(z)}{x^2}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=-\frac{\sin(z)}{x}
$$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Above, each partial takes the derivative of $f$ "without care" for the other variables, as is what I believe is the case in your inquiry. Let me know if this helps or if I'm getting at the wrong angle, maybe by clarifying your question.

Comment: Ye sthank you for the help, actualy the msitake was mine, i did not writte explicitly that this is a composition, i will rewrite, but the idea is that r,s,u,v are compositions of x and y..., this is the issue, even so thank you :)